# Custom view with rounded corners in Android

Tags: android-view, android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view which contains several layers of images, layouts with texts, drawings etc.
I want to make one of the corners of the view round (top-right corner).
In other words, I want to crop this corner to make it round - not to set rounded corner background.

I managed to do it by using `clipPath()`, but it's running slow since I had to turn the hardware acceleration for this view - so this solution is not suited for me.

Any other way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using an XML Drawable?  That might suit your purposes.  You can pull off lots of interesting shapes using a layer list.

Comment: I tried it, but AFAIK it only applies the rounded corner to the background, not to the whole view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the custom rounded ImageView class extending ImageView. And here variable CORNER_RADIUS is the value of radius. Using this code you can create any rounded view just by extending that class from that view.

```
public class RoundedImage extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
 {
private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 100.0f;

private Bitmap maskBitmap;
private Paint paint, maskPaint;
private float cornerRadius;

public RoundedImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);

}

public RoundedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RoundedImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

    super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

    if (maskBitmap == null) {
        maskBitmap = createMask(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
}

private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
    Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

    return mask;
}
```

}

How to use is:

```
<com.packagename.RoundedImage
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scaleType="centercrop"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem if you create a transparent canvas for that custom view. Then draw a rounded rectangle on it as a background before the rest of the graphics.

The rounded rectangle should be bigger than the canvas and shifted to the left so that the top-right corner of the canvas stays transparent.

However is you draw biger images in your custom view and want just to clip that corner than you can just erase that corner with a corner shape Path filled with a paint

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: I tried it like that:  @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.draw(canvas);
   final Paint paint = new Paint();
  Path p = new Path();
  p.addArc(new RectF(0, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()), 90, -90);
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
  canvas.drawPath(p, paint); }  -- Doesn;t seem to work, just paints the arc in black above my view

Comment: This seems to be more complicated. When you draw this directly on canvas it drills a hole to the default activity background which is black. I cannot find an example of a custom view which allows clearing canvas directly. One way around this is to create a bitmap and draw everything on it, then clear the corner with Mode.Clear. Then draw that bitmap on the canvas. Every time you invalidate the canvas it will be cleared and made transparent so you can draw your bitmap again. The bitmap must be RGBA_8888.

Comment: I think the cheapes way would be to paint the corner with the same colour as the backround, but the bitmap option is actually fast and devices are much more powerful nowadays.